# Do my tomatoes have aminopyralid herbicide damage?

Tags: diseases, tomatoes, compost, herbicide, wind-damage

Photo below of my tomato plant. This was planted in 3 inches of miracle grow with composted horse manure below, sourced locally. Everything was fine for about 2 weeks, then this morning I noticed that all of the new plant growth  at the top has this aggressive curling. Is this herbicide contamination from the horse manure compost?

[image: Possible aminopyralid damage]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomatoes are hyper sensitive to herbicides , it can drift hundreds of feet from an application area and affect tomatoes. And, yes, herbicide in a compost can affect them. My son got some free rich garden compost from a retirement home that was closing down a garden area ; filled his pickup truck. He used it as addition to a few raised vegetable beds. Almost no vegetable would grow in the beds for at least two years.  There was only circumstantial evidence that the retirement home had used heavy herbicide in the garden ( residents told him).

Comment: But is the damage in the photo for certain caused by herbicide?

Comment: Probably , I think you would need expensive chemical testing to prove it in court.